# OpenCV sequences -- how to create a sequence of point pairs?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create an empty sequence (`CvSeq`) in `OpenCV` similar in structure to the one returned by, for example, `cvHoughLines2` (when used in `CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC`) - a sequence of point pairs.

I have found a way to make a sequence of (unconnected) points (I hope this is correct for a point sequence):

```
CvMemStorage *memStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq(
             CV_SEQ_FLAG_SIMPLE | CV_SEQ_KIND_SET | CV_SEQ_ELTYPE_POINT,
             sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), memStorage);
```

but looking at the flags available for creating `CvSeq` I can not find anything I could use to construct a sequence whose elements would be point pairs. I would like to access the elements of my created sequence in the same way I access the lines I get from the Hough Transform:

```
for (int i=0; i < mylines->total; ++i){
    CvPoint *line = (CvPoint *)cvGetSeqElem(mylines, i);

    ...

    ... line[0].x ...
    ... line[1].y ... 

    ...
}
```

Also, how would I insert elements in such a sequence? :/

The reason for the question is that I already have quite a complex function operating on a `CvSeq` of lines returned by a `cvHoughLines2()` function, and I would like to use it on some arbitrary lines I would create in the picture (testing purposes, etc...). I have looked all over for an answer to a similar question, but couldn't find anything... :(

Thank you all very much for your help!

### EDIT: found the solution.

Looks like the only thing that needs to be done is to omit the flags completely, indicating that you will not be using any of the predefined types (e.g points), and just give the right size of the sequence component:

```
CvMemStorage *memStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint)*2, memStorage);
```

I can than add to the storage by passing the pointer to a 2-point array to the `push` function:

```
CvPoint points[2];
... (initialize the points) ...
cvSeqPush(seq, &points);
```

This way I can access the sequence in the same way I accessed the output of the Hough Transform.

Comment: Hi Penelope, if you use C++, please learn the C++ API of OpenCV.

Comment: Btw. +1 for coming back to line out the solution!

Comment: ypnos, I know I probably should learn C++ OpenCV API for my future projects, but the only literature I had available in paper form was the Bradski Kaehler book from 2008 (with only the C API). And it's really hard for me to learn something big from online materials :(

Comment: http://opencv.itseez.com/, the latest opencv document

Comment: @zhanwu: Awesome. 0.o This will help a lot in future.

Comment: @penelope Please add your EDIT as an answer and then accept it. (You can accept your own answers.) That way it will be easy to find for someone else having this same problem.

Comment: You must call cvCreateSeq with CV_SEQ_ELTYPE_POINT flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After 20 minutes searching for a solution in order to help, I read the entire question and found a solution edit. *Copy and paste*, in order to get this question out of *unanswered*.

Looks like the **only thing that needs to be done is to omit the flags completely**, indicating that you will not be using any of the predefined types (e.g points), and just give the right size of the sequence component:

```
CvMemStorage *memStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint)*2, memStorage);
```

I can than add to the storage by passing the pointer to a 2-point array to the push function:

```
CvPoint points[2];
... (initialize the points) ...
cvSeqPush(seq, &points);
```

This way I can access the sequence in the same way I accessed the output of the Hough Transform.

Comment: This should have been a comment on the user question telling him to add his solution as an answer and then accept it. I'm very tempted to down vote your answer, @robermorales

Comment: @karlphillip, there is already a comment, and an edit. but for no looking deeper, I found myself searching for a non-needed answer, avoiding me helping others. I think it is a better alternative, not for my reputation, for keeping the question out of the "unanswered" list.

Comment: I know, I read the entire question and up voted that comment before coming to your answer and telling you that. Living and learning my dear friend, now you know that in the future you'll save a lot of time and pain just by paying attention to what is being asked. And I disagree with you. This user seems to contribute to the site and will probably come back to fix this issue. There's no need for us to copy/paste his answer here.