# create a customized sequence of CvPoint in OpenCv

Tags: opencv, sequence, contour

I want to use cvDrawContours to draw my own contours created from CvSeq (normally, contours are retured from other functions of OpenCV). This is my solution but it does not work :(

```
IplImage*    g_gray    = NULL;

CvMemStorage *memStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0); 
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint)*4, memStorage); 


CvPoint points[4]; 
points[0].x = 10;
points[0].y = 10;
points[1].x = 1;
points[1].y = 1;
points[2].x = 20;
points[2].y = 50;
points[3].x = 10;
points[3].y = 10;

cvSeqPush(seq, &points); 

g_gray = cvCreateImage( cvSize(300,300), 8, 1 );

cvNamedWindow( "MyContour", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

cvDrawContours( 
    g_gray, 
    seq, 
    cvScalarAll(100),
    cvScalarAll(255),
    0,
    3);

cvShowImage( "MyContour", g_gray );

cvWaitKey(0);  

cvReleaseImage( &g_gray );
cvDestroyWindow("MyContour");

return 0;
```

I picked the method to create a customized contour sequence from CvPoint from this post 
[OpenCV sequences -- how to create a sequence of point pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984994/opencv-sequences-how-to-create-a-sequence-of-point-pairs)

FOr the second try, I did it with Cpp OpenCV:

```
vector<vector<Point2i>> contours;
Point2i P;
P.x = 0;
P.y = 0;
contours.push_back(P);
P.x = 50;
P.y = 10;
contours.push_back(P);
P.x = 20;
P.y = 100;
contours.push_back(P);

Mat img = imread(file, 1);
drawContours(img, contours, -1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 5, 8);
```

Perhaps I used the data incorrectly. The compiler alerts errors & does not allow push_back points to vectors like that. Why??

The error is like this:
Error   2   error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cv::Point2i' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'

Comment: I have tried OpenCV C++. But still cannot work out. Perhaps I used it incorrectly. I added my trial in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally finished it.

```
Mat g_gray_cpp = imread(file, 0);  

vector<vector<Point2i>> contours; 
vector<Point2i> pvect;
Point2i P(0,0);

pvect.push_back(P);

P.x = 50;
P.y = 10;   
pvect.push_back(P);

P.x = 20;
P.y = 100;
pvect.push_back(P);

contours.push_back(pvect);

Mat img = imread(file, 1);

drawContours(img, contours, -1, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 5, 8);

namedWindow( "Contours", 0 );
imshow( "Contours", img );
```

because 'contours' is vector>, contours.push_back(var)  -> var should be a vector

Thanks! I've learnt a bug

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you created a sequence of point foursomes with single element. Sequence `elem_size` should be `sizeof(CvPoint)` (not multiplied by four) and add points one by one:

```c
CvMemStorage *memStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0); 
// without these flags the drawContours() method does not consider the sequence
// as contour and just draws nothing
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq(CV_32SC2 | CV_SEQ_KIND_CURVE, 
      sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), memStorage); 

cvSeqPush(cvPoint(10, 10));
cvSeqPush(cvPoint(1, 1));
cvSeqPush(cvPoint(20, 50));
```

Note you don't need to insert the last point to draw the contour, contour is automatically closed.